# Property 'schedule' does not exist on type 'typeof import().ts'

Tags: properties, nativescript, schedule

I am just a new learner and following a video tutorial, my code looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; 
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish'; 
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service'; 
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'; 
import {map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { CouchbaseService } from '../services/couchbase.service';
import * as LocalNotifications from 'nativescript-local-notifications';


@Injectable() 
export class FavoriteService {

    favorites: Array<number>;
    docId: string = "favorites";

    constructor(private dishservice: DishService,
        private couchbaseService: CouchbaseService) { 
        this.favorites = [];

        let doc = this.couchbaseService.getDocument(this.docId);
        if( doc == null) {
            this.couchbaseService.createDocument({"favorites": []}, this.docId);
        }
        else {
            this.favorites = doc.favorites;
        }
    }

    isFavorite(id: number): boolean { 
        return this.favorites.some(el => el === id); 
    }

    addFavorite(id: number): boolean {
        if (!this.isFavorite(id)) {
            this.favorites.push(id);
            this.couchbaseService.updateDocument(this.docId, {"favorites": this.favorites});

            // Schedule a single notification
            LocalNotifications.schedule([{
                id: id,
                title: "ConFusion Favorites",
                body: 'Dish ' + id + ' added successfully'
            }])
            .then(() => console.log('Notification scheduled'),
                (error) => console.log('Error showing nofication ' + error));
        }
        return true;
    }

    getFavorites(): Observable<Dish[]> { 
        return this.dishservice.getDishes() 
        .pipe(map(dishes => dishes.filter(dish => this.favorites.some(el => el === dish.id)))); 
    }

    deleteFavorite(id: number): Observable<Dish[]> {
        let index = this.favorites.indexOf(id);
        if (index >= 0) {
          this.favorites.splice(index,1);
          this.couchbaseService.updateDocument(this.docId, {"favorites": this.favorites});
          return this.getFavorites();
        }
        else {
          console.log('Deleting non-existant favorite', id);
          return Observable.throw('Deleting non-existant favorite');
        }
    }
}
```

And the error I got is:

> Property 'schedule' does not exist on type 'typeof
>   import("c:/Users/m/Desktop/JS/conFusion/node_modules/nativescript-local-notifications/index")'.ts(2339)

I don't know what is the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: Try `import { LocalNotifications } from 'nativescript-local-notifications';` as mentioned in plugin docs.

Comment: @Manoj: cool! seems it worked!

Comment: I had a similar error, my problem was I had two files, my-file.json and my-file.ts, unfortunately it was importing the json file instead of the ts file. The solution was to rename the json file to something else so that importing from 'my-file' then worked as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the plugin's read me file, use named import

```
import { LocalNotifications } from 'nativescript-local-notifications';
```